# Display color mode settings vs Windows / Software color profiles, AdobeRGB

Tags: adobe-photoshop, display-settings, color-profiles

I have monitor with 99% Adobe RGB and 95% DCI-P3.
For the color space in OSD settings, Standard = Adobe RGB, DCI = DCI-P3, sRGB = sRGB (sic!)
In Windows color management default one is set to sRGB profile (IEC).

Now I want to see that 99% Adobe RGB inside Photoshop. What's the best way to achive that?

1. Standard OSD settings + AdobeRGB color profile in Photoshop
2. Standard OSD settings + AdobeRGB color profile in Windows
3. Some other OSD settings
4. You know nothing

Also I consider X-Rite calibration that will give me custom ICM profile. But I guess there is no all around good solution, and I always gonna end up messing with OSD settings.
For day to day usage like web browsing I should stick with sRGB color mode + no color profile in Windows.
Photoshop equels changing OSD settings to Standard, or is it still 4? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly 4 ;)

You calibrate the screen using the OSD controls until the X-Rite software is 'happy' then you never touch them again.

The X-Rite will then make a screen profile based on measurement of the response of that initial calibration & install it as your OS's default icc profile. You never touch that again [until next month when you recalibrate]

You do not set Photoshop's working space to your screen profile, you set a working space - choose between sRGB, Adobe RGB etc based on your most common output workflow, but also set to preserve embedded profiles. Basically that means you work in eg your camera's profile until Export, at which time you convert to your desired output profile.

You then view different colour modes by using Photoshop to 'Convert to Profile'.
Note this will only really appear to do anything visible if you are stepping 'down', eg from P3 to sRGB. Stepping 'up', ie to a wider gamut, will not invent new colours that weren't in the original image.
Also note that most people don't have screens even capable of accurately displaying sRGB, but at least they make an attempt, so that's your best output for most things other than print.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's a little bit more clear. If I understand it correctly, picking Standard mode aka AdobeRGB from OSD + calibration should give me also good representation of colors when something is only sRGB capable, like browser?

Comment: Once you have everything calibrated, then whatever profile is embedded in an image should correctly dictate how you see it [with the caveat that some apps on windows ignore profiles & assume everything is sRGB, but that's really a Windows issue, nothing you can do about it other than switch to a Mac ;) Any 'proper' graphics app should be OK, of course.